# The symbol grounding problem, physicalism and 2nd law of thermodynamics?

Tags: physics, physicalism, information, philosophy-of-information

How does a physicalist resolve this dilemma (and what is it known as)?

Consider a physicalist who wants to solve the symbol grounding problem. He postulates that a particular brain configuration corresponds to a particular meaning. He gives this postulate the status of a law.

I don't think this solution can work? Why? Let's assume this solution is true. Then by merely knowing what you are experiencing you tell that to a computer in the form of some code. The computer uses an internal dictionary that corresponds to a particular physical configuration.

Essentially the computer has done negligible work to find the configuration of your brain. I don't see why the.computer now cannot "game' this and violate the second law of thermodynamics.

The situation is analogous to Maxwell's demon but this time the gas is telling him it's state.

How does the physicalist proceed? And what is this argument known as?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of links(/references) but I'm currently on my phone

Comment: Could you elaborate what that has to do with the second law of thermodynamics? I mean you could argue by mere correlation of signals coming from different sensors and being processed by different brain regions you'd form connections between simultaneously active regions so that speech is connected to emotions and symbols to speech.

Comment: @haxor789 see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/information-entropy/ section 3.3. Maxwell's demon (when applied to this situation) is able to extract information about the system without paying the corresponding thermodynamic cost.

Comment: Sorry I meant section 3.1 Measurement with light

Comment: Whats being described here is brain entropy.There is recent research regarding consciousness and brain entropy that may be of interest:

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29432427/#:~:text=Entropy%20measures%20the%20variety%20of,a%20given%20brain%20can%20access.
https://physicsworld.com/a/consciousness-is-tied-to-entropy-say-researchers/

Comment: You did not specify any method by which the computer can violate the 2nd law in this setup, so I don't know what you expect answers to talk about here. Also: 
1. The human has to perform some work to encode their subjective experience in a form that can be input into the computer and/or the computer then has to expend work to parse this information. 2. The computer has to perform work to retrieve the corresponding dictionary entry from storage. Both storage and retrieval are not free operations, either. Your question seems to assume these costs are negligible without any argument.

Comment: It seems like you are just remarking on an extreme sort of data compression here. You can say "I'm hungry", and this represents a very complex brain state. But of course it wouldn't represent a single brain state. There would be many brain states corresponding to that report.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I was talking to Acuriousmind and he also raised this point. To which I argue even having a probability distribution of what the the I'm hungry state corresponds to would suffice to best the 2nd law.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62490801#62490801

Answer (score 1):

> Let's assume this solution is true. Then by merely knowing what you are experiencing you tell that to a computer in the form of some code.

To begin with, the consistent physicalist would certainly not believe that he is telling the computer what he is experiencing. He would probably say that some physical process inside his brain causes him to say something to the computer.

Second, he would not accept that the computer would thereby know anything about the state of his brain. In the physicalist's world, actual knowledge just does not exist. It would be a physical interaction. The physicalist would do something thereby causing the computer to do something else. Whatever smart software the computer would be loaded with, it could not possibly have any 100% correct representation of the physicalist's brain. There is no magic in the physicalist's world. Whatever would be going on exactly, entropy would keep increasing in the process.